# ArcSight ESM - custom dashboard to display video

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, xpack, arcsight

I want to create a custom dashboard to display video, in ArcSight ESM.

[image]

I had spent a couple of hours to find solutions but no luck. Please anyone can guide me how can I accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With ArcSight ESM, if you want to customize the Command Center to display videos, it is not possible yet.

Font: I'm ArcSight Enginner.